# SQL Server Expres 2016 + SSMS2016, no backup command in the popup?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I'm trying SQL Express 2016 + SSMS2016 on a new machine, then I see this: there is no backup command. Maybe I need to turn on some settings? Anyone else has this issue? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Seeing the exact same thing. Version: 13.0.15000.23 .. Super odd.

Comment: are you using SSD? could it be because of that? unlikely, but who knows.

Comment: Who is not :-) no sorry yes I am using a ssd drive, but 2014 had no problems wit doing the backup on the same drive.

Comment: very odd. But the TSQL backup works.

Comment: It looks like it.. I just did a               backup database xxxx to 'd:\xxxx.bck'

Answer (score 0):

Install SSMS separately from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I have currently installed version 13.0.15000.23. It has backup option.

Comment: I'm actually using the exact same version, weird, no backup.

Comment: Is this behavior for ALL databases? Have you tried to restore AdventureWorks and see how it looks like?

Comment: did not try AdventureWorks, but somehow all databases I restored on this express 2016, all has no backup.

Comment: Can you connect your SSMS to another server to make sure it is not SSMS installation problem? If not, you can try to install Enterprise Evaluation and see how it will work there.

Comment: connect to another SQL server, everything works fine. Seems it is because of SQL express 2016. even new database does not have the backup menu.